# Google Map: not change size in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a application using Google Maps API and I have developed a controller to set full screen when user click in a button using this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Non-standard_methods

But the problem is in full screen show more map than in normal screen. And the application must show excactly the same part of the map in both views.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to change the zoom on the map, but that is unlikely to be exact.

Comment: But the zooms level are not exactly and not show the same part :(

Comment: Can you post your code so far?